# Activate browser's popup with HTML pattern and RegEx

Tags: javascript, html

once again I need your help! I am building a simple form, which you can see down in the snippet. I am using pattern with RegEx in the IBAN field, because it has to be exactly 22 characters in my country.

I must make this `input` type a `button` type and use it with `onclick` and `function`. But without submitting the form, the

> 'Please match the requested format'

Browser PopUp doesn't work. Can someone explain to me why is that and how can I manage to fix it?

P.S. I want the `input` to be of type `button`

```html
<form action="" method="POST">

<span class="span-recepient-iban">IBAN<br/></span>
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Z0-9]{22}" title="Must be exactly 22 characters (words and numbers only)" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

Comment: so, you have a submit button, onClick of which you don't want form to be submitted? Instead you have to call a function?

Comment: Yes, I don't want the form to be submitted, I just want to use `input type="button" onclick="function()"`, but if I do it this way, the PopUp which is triggered by RegEx doesn't show, because the form isn't submitted.

Comment: check if the code works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Used custom validation : `setCustomValidity`

```js
function onSubmit(e) {

  var field = document.getElementById("field");

  var constraint = new RegExp('^(CH-)?\\d{4}$', "");

  if (constraint.test(field.value)) {
    field.setCustomValidity("");
  }
  else {
    field.setCustomValidity("Your msg");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="field"> 
    <input type="submit" onclick="onSubmit(event)" value="Validate">
</form>
```

@Bogdan Lozev Hope this is what you want to achieve

Comment: its' working fine , but try this with `input type="button"` , because this is my target, and it won't work.

Comment: @BogdanLozev why do you want to use `type="button"`, what do you want to do in that ?

Comment: I was just wondering... why the browsers popups (dialog boxes) are triggered only when submitting the form and not when trying to use `onclick` event...

Comment: @BogdanLozev you should have post this question instead :p

Answer (score 0):

You missed the attribute `required=''` for input field.

```html
<form action="" method="POST">

  <span class="span-recepient-iban">IBAN<br/></span>
  <input type="text" pattern="[A-Z0-9]{22}" title="Must be exactky 22 characters (words and numbers only)" required='' />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

Comment: Try changing `input type="submit"` with `input type="button"` and see that it is not working.

Comment: @BogdanLozev, your OP has `submit` and not `button`

Comment: I did it that way, so you can see your browser dialog box, saying "Please match the requested format", but I want this dialog box to be triggered with `input type="button"` NOT `input type="submit"`.